# Discrepancy in the calculation of $2$-Selmer group by Magma and LMFDB

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, elliptic-curves, computer-science

The result of LMFDB claims (https://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/Q/1640/c/1 )
that (2-part of) Tate-Shafarevich group $\mathrm{Sha}(E/\Bbb{Q})$ of elliptic curve $y^2=x^3-8747x-314874$ has order $16$. In particular, the order of $2$-Selmer group is larger than $16$.

But Magma calculates as following,

```
A:=EllipticCurve([0,0,0,-8747,-314874]); 
Sel2:=TwoSelmerGroup(A); Sel2;
```

The output of this is,

```
Abelian Group isomorphic to Z/2 + Z/2 + Z/2 Defined on 3 generators Relations:
    2*Sel2.1 = 0
    2*Sel2.2 = 0
    2*Sel2.3 = 0
```

It seems contradiction because $2$-Selmer group is larger than $2$-part of Tate-Shafarevich group.

Where did I go wrong and how can I correctly calculate order of $2$-Selmer group using Magma ?

Comment: I suspect Magma's TwoSelmerGroup function is only computing the 2-torsion part of the Selmer group $Sel_2$, *not* the 2-primary part $Sel_{2^\infty}$. If the Tate-Shafarevich group has some elements of order 4 then that would explain the apparent discrepancy.

Comment: I don't understand the vote to close here. Although the question was based on a misconception, it's a pretty subtle and plausible mistake, and I think the discussion might still be informative for future readers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't see any contradiction: the Selmer group also has a contribution of rational points. Indeed, the group of 2-torsion rational points on this elliptic curve is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ and generated by $(-54,0)$, as Magma will readily confirm (probably, I used GP/Pari).

UPDATE: As David suspected, the Tate-Shafarevic group of this elliptic curve is isomorphic to $(\mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z)^2$ so 2-descent misses the elements of order 4 in Sha.

Comment: It's the other way around: the problem is that the computations are (allegedly) saying that Sha is *bigger* than Selmer.

Comment: It is as you suspected in your comment: Pari confirms by 2-descent that Sha is $(\mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z)^2$, so it has elements of order 4, whereas the function used in the question only computes the 2-torsion part of the Selmer group.